# sklearn TfidfVectorizer custom ngrams without characters from regex pattern

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I would like to perform custom ngram vectorization using [sklearn TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). The generated ngrams should not contain any character from a given regex pattern. Unfortunately the custom tokenizer function is completely ignored when `analyzer='char'` (ngram mode). See the following example:

```py
import re
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

pattern = re.compile(r'[\.-]'). # split on '.' and on '-'

def tokenize(text):
    return pattern.split(text)

corpus = np.array(['abc.xyz', 'zzz-m.j'])

# word vectorization
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, analyzer='word', stop_words='english')
tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_)
# Output -> {'abc': 0, 'xyz': 3, 'zzz': 4, 'm': 2, 'j': 1}
# This is ok!

# ngram vectorization
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, analyzer='char', ngram_range=(2, 2))
tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_)
# Output -> {'ab': 3, 'bc': 4, 'c.': 5, '.x': 2, 'xy': 7, 'yz': 8, 'zz': 10, 'z-': 9, '-m': 0, 'm.': 6, '.j': 1}
# This is not ok! I don't want ngrams to include the '.' and '-' chars used for tokenization
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written the following solution using `nltk`:

```py
import re
from nltk.util import ngrams
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

pattern = re.compile(r'[\.-]'). # split on '.' and on '-'

corpus = np.array(['abc.xyz', 'zzz-m.j'])


def analyzer(text):
    text = text.lower()
    tokens = pattern.split(text)    
    return [''.join(ngram) for token in tokens for ngram in ngrams(token, 2)]

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=analyzer)
tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_)

# Output -> {'ab': 0, 'bc': 1, 'xy': 2, 'yz': 3, 'zz': 4}
```

Not sure if this is the best way to go though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), you can use `tokenizer` only when the `analyzer=word`. Here is their exact words:

> tokenizer (default=None)
>   Override the string tokenization step while preserving the preprocessing and n-grams generation steps. Only applies if analyzer == 'word'.

There a workaround that you can do which is to remove all the tokens that have either `.` or `-` in them from the vocabulary. The following code does so:

```
from copy import copy


for token in copy(tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_):
    if re.search(pattern, token):
        del tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_[token]

print(tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_)
#{'ab': 3, 'bc': 4, 'xy': 7, 'yz': 8, 'zz': 10}
```

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I am asking

Comment: I've edited my answer with a workaround to produce exactly what you want